# Should Keycloak be used in my website user registration and log in?

Tags: authentication, jboss, facebook-login, keycloak

I am using JBoss JSF to develop a personal project, and the website needs a user registration and login feature, as many other sites do. There are lots of tutorials on how to develop a user registration component in Java EE and JPA framework. I just happened to find the KeyCloak project. It seems that KeyCloak can be used for user registration and management purpose, especially if you use JBoss to develop the application.

My question is, do I really need to use this for user registration? It seems very heavy, and I didn't find any API docs that I can refer to integrate it into my web application.

What's the best use case of Keycloak? And how to integrate it in a Java EE application? Any quickstart or tutorial for Java application would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The main Keycloak project includes a [adapters documentation](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/ch08.html) (to be used to secure clients) [examples project](http://downloads.jboss.org/keycloak/1.7.0.Final/keycloak-examples-1.7.0.Final.zip) showing how to secure a JEE application using JEE application security.

If you use Spring, there's a [Spring Security adapter](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/ch08.html#spring-security-adapter) that support a more very flexible security implementation as well, including [examples](https://github.com/foo4u/keycloak-spring-demo) for this as well.